# Factoring polynomial $x^3−2x^2−4x−8$ that fails Bezout's identity test

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I usually factor 3rd degree polynomial in two steps. First, I find all the divisors of the last, coefficient-free part of the polynomial (in this case that's 8) and try (applying Bezout's identity) to plug them into P(x) one by one until I get zero. When I find divisor $d$ that passes the test, I know my polynomial is divisible by $(x - d)$. 
Then, I do my division and get a quadratic polynomial, which I factor using the formula for solving quadratic equations (I guess I *could* continue testing via Bezout's but I prefer this way). And that's how I get three factors of 3rd degree polynomial. But in this case, my method fails at step one, because $±1, ±2, ±4, ±8$ do not give zero as a result when plugged into the beginning polynomial.

I also tried factoring it "by hand", meaning, I tried to find common factor between two pairs of the polynomial, but failed. You get $(x−2)x^2−4(x+2)$, so no root there.

How could I solve this? Are candidates for Bezout's test divisors of the free polynomial member **only**? Can every 3rd degree polynomial be factored in $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ form in R and C?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $x^3+x$ can't be factored over the reals...

Comment: One thing is sure with third degree polynomials: they have at least one real root. But take $x^3+1$... How many real roots?

Answer (score 0):

Your polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Its only real root is irrational, namely $$\frac{2+\sqrt[3]{152-24\sqrt{33}}+2\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}3\not\in\mathbb Q$$ The same goes for the other two, whose expressions can also be deduced using the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots). Perhaps you are confused by thinking that cubic conjugate roots come in pairs, just like [quadratic conjugate roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Radical_conjugate_roots). They don't. They come in [triples](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196).